# GoogleMock SetArgReferee behavior for polymorphic arguments

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I'm attempting to mock a DB interface call and return a polymorphic data type as a reference using `SetArgReferee`. The method I'm mocking takes 2 base class reference arguments. While setting the value for the 2nd reference argument in `SetArgReferee`, a derived class object is used as the value. In the source code under test, the returned 2nd reference argument is again cast to the derived class and used. This seems to be not working properly.

I have a `DBInterface` that I'm mocking as below.

```
class DBInterface {
...
public:
    virtual void service(Msg& req, Msg& resp, bool flag) = 0;
...
};

class DBInterfaceMock : public DBInterface {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD3(service, void(Msg& req, Msg& resp, bool flag));
};
```

The test mocks this service call using the `EXPECT_CALL` as shown below

```
TEST_F(SessionTest, SessionInt) {
    DBInterfaceMock mockDb;
    Session* session = new Session(mockDb);
    // DerivedMsg inherits from Msg and contains a map
    DerivedMsg derivedMsg;
    // populating the map inside the derivedMsg
    // ...
    // ...

    EXPECT_CALL(mockDb, service(_, _, false))
        .Times(1)
        .WillDo(SetArgReferee<1>(*(dynamic_cast<Msg*>(&derivedMsg))));

    session->init();
    ....
    ....
}
```

On calling the `session->init()`, I'm expecting that the mocked service call must return the values as populated in `derivedMsg`. However, the code hits an `ASSERT` where the map size is `0` even though the value to be returned in the `SetArgReferee` has been populated correctly.
In the production code, once the service call executes successfully, the reference argument is retrieved by doing a `dynamic_cast` to the desired derived type as shown below.

```
service(req, resp, false);
DerivedMsg derivedResp = *(dynamic_cast<DerivedMsg*>(&resp));

uint16_t size = derivedResp.getMap().size(); //returns a 0 size.
```

Is there a better way of achieving this? It doesn't seem to be working this way.

Comment: `DBInterface::service` should be `virtual` and `DBInterfaceMock` should inherit from `DBInterface`. Are those typos in the question or errors in your code?

Comment: Thanks Antonio. Had missed it in the code snippet.